# MVC with Entity Framework My DropDownList isn't a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been following [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial which shows you how to populate a drop down list. However my create page doesn't show a drop down list at all but shows this

[image]

This is my drop down list code in my UserController.cs

```
private void PopulateAdministratorsDropDownList(object selectedAdministrator = null)
{
    var administratorQuery = from d in db.Administrators
                           orderby d.AdministratorTitle
                             select d;
    ViewBag.AdministratorID = new SelectList(administratorQuery, "AdministratorID", "AdministratorTitle", selectedAdministrator);
}
```

Views\User\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        .... // more controls
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdministratorID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdministratorID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdministratorID)
        </div>
        ....
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

UserController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    PopulateAdministratorsDropDownList();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate,AdministratorID, DepartmentID, DepotID")]User user)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }
    PopulateAdministratorsDropDownList(user.AdministratorID);
    return View(user);
}

private void PopulateAdministratorsDropDownList(object selectedAdministrator = null)
{
    var administratorQuery = from d in db.Administrators
                             orderby d.AdministratorTitle
                             select d;
    ViewBag.AdministratorID = new SelectList(administratorQuery, "AdministratorID", "AdministratorTitle", selectedAdministrator);
}
```

Comment: Change it to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdministratorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AdministratorList)` - not that you need to change the name of the `ViewBag` property - it cannot be the same name as the property your binding to.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AdministratorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AdministratorID)`

Comment: Note also that there is no point adding the last parameter (`selectedAdministrator`) in the `SelectList` constructor - its ignored by the HtmlHelper when binding to a model property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you're following the tut, but you don't follow it exactly. Instead use `@Html.DropDownListFor` when you want to get a dropdown.

In the link you posted they use the following for the `Department` dropdown; like so:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID, "Department")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
</div>
```

but yours looks like:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdministratorID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdministratorID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdministratorID)
</div>
```

They're not equivalent.

Side note: The tutorial you following is not following best practice (using the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method), and using `DropDownList()` will also mean that you do not get any client side validation (if you inspect the generated html you will note there are no `data-val-*` attributes in the `<select>` tag). Instead, use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdministratorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AdministratorList, "Please select")
```

and change the name of your ViewBag property (it cannot be the same name as the property your binding to)

```
ViewBag.AdministratorList = new SelectList(administratorQuery, "AdministratorID", "AdministratorTitle")
```

Comment: It's because they usually highlight the code in yellow for codes that need to be changed but they didn't do it for that part.

Comment: @JasonWan, that seems like a valid statement given the imgs.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I wouldn't mind you making a comment with your strongly typed version. Of course I don't want bad practice with my coding. `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdministratorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AdministratorList)` Strongly Typed?

Comment: @JasonWan, I believe they hint at it in their comment on your question -`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdministratorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.AdministratorList) `. I'm rusty so I won't try to paste that in without knowing what's going on.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Of course! You've answered my question which is more than enough.

Comment: @JasonWan, Where ever possible, use the strongly type helpers (i.e. those with `xxxxFor()` - they were introduced in MVC-2). There are many benefits including avoiding the use of 'magic' strings - had you misspelled "AdministratorID"  or later changed the property name, you could spend ages trying to track it down. Using the strongly type helpers will make it immediately obvious because of the error message.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, I realize you were just following the code in the tutorial, so I have edited your answer to include 'best' practice :) (although best practice would also include using a view model with `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AdministratorList` rather than using `ViewBag`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for the improvements; I owe you 1.